# Database user scenario with multiple type of user

Tags: mysql, database-design, yii, normalization

I am designing a database for a Yii project, the scenario is a user will be ONLY one of the following type: employee, company and business owner person (i.e. the owners who manage companies and employees - super admin - I broke the many to many relationship that's why I call the table "business_owner_person"). Below is how I designed my database in MySQL:

### USER

- id,
- username,
- password,
- active

### COMPANY

- id,
- name,
- contact_no,
- contact_name,
- address...
- user_id (FK)

### EMPLOYEE

- id,
- first_name,
- surname,
- address,
- email...
- company_id (FK)
- user_id (FK)

### BUSINESS_OWNER_PERSON

- id,
- name,
- email,
- position...
- user_id (FK)

I am just wondering if there is a better/efficient way to design this scenario so that Yii won't have the problem to fetch the correct additional informations for user.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to make suggestions without knowing a little more about the business, but it seems like you have too much redundant information.

Splitting out the user is good, since any of these types of people can be a user.  I would probably put the common information, name, email into the user field, maybe even the address and position.

Then what it looks like you want is that a user can have one or more roles, where the role controls their level of access.  This could be as simple, to start out with as a role_id columns in the DB table, or it could be a separate table, user_id, role_id.

Now, all that being said, it's difficult to make suggestions without more information.  Do you need to isolate users by company?  Will there be a lot of companies?  How many business owners are you looking at having?

Comment: The business owners handle a lot of companies as their contractors and each contractor has many employees, the client want to call a contractor a company, employee and company will both have a user each, i will definitely add role in the user table, the relationship will be one to many. As for business owners they will have various account and each business owner has a distinct position like project manager, supervisors but all of them are admin with slight difference in their functionality. I like your suggestion of adding more details to user table.